# Joining two MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to combine two queries.

The first gives me all registrations in a specific month.

```
SELECT player_id from player where registration_datetime like '%2013-12%';
```

The second query finds users that have logged in in Jan, Feb and March

```
SELECT player_id
                        FROM login_history
                        GROUP BY player_id
                        HAVING SUM(timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01 00:00:00') AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00')-1)) > 0 and
                               SUM(timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00') AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-01 00:00:00')-1)) > 0 and
                               SUM(timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-01 00:00:00') AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-04-01 00:00:00')-1)) > 0
                         ;
```

How can I find the common player_id's between the two queries without using an IN ?

Thanks

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you've not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you've not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2):

you could use an `UNION ALL` on your 2 queries, `group by player_id` and `having count(*) > 1`

or use an inner join (I would add a distinct in the joined query)

```
SELECT player_id
FROM login_history
join (SELECT distinct player_id from player where registration_datetime like '%2013-12%') s
  on s.player_id = player_id                   
GROUP BY player_id
HAVING SUM(timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01 00:00:00') AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00')-1)) > 0 and
       SUM(timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00') AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-01 00:00:00')-1)) > 0 and
       SUM(timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-01 00:00:00') AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-04-01 00:00:00')-1)) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

sqlfiddle would be nice.

But did you try joining these two tables and then grouping data?

Something like this:

```
SELECT p.player_id FROM player p 
JOIN login_history lh ON p.player_id = lh.player_id
WHERE p.registration_datetime like '%2013-12%'
GROUP BY p.player_id
HAVING SUM(lh.timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01 00:00:00') AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00')-1)) > 0 and
       SUM(lh.timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00') AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-01 00:00:00')-1)) > 0 and
       SUM(lh.timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-01 00:00:00') AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-04-01 00:00:00')-1)) > 0;
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. It also made it easy to change the periods for checking... Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery and a join to accomplish this. The first part of the query returns the player id from player. The second part subsets your login_history to only the ids you want, ones in which the user logged in between Jan and March. This table is joined with players, giving you only the ids of users who registered in Jan and logged in during Jan, Feb, and Mar

```
SELECT a.player_id 
FROM player AS a 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT player_id
FROM login_history
GROUP BY player_id
HAVING SUM(timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01 00:00:00') AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00')-1)) > 0 AND
SUM(timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00') AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-01 00:00:00')-1)) > 0 AND
SUM(timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-01 00:00:00') AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-04-01 00:00:00')-1)) > 0) AS b
ON a.player_id = b.player_id
WHERE a.registration_datetime like '%2013-12%'
```